# How to set up a filter in google analytics api on pagePath?

Tags: filter, google-analytics

So when using the api I generally pass parameters ilke this:
1.       Date from and to
2.       Dimensions
3.       Metrics
4.       Profiles

Example call would include this for example:

```
(start_date=2015-05-31&end_date=2015-05-31&dimensions=ga:date,ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:sessions,ga:users,ga:bounces,ga:exits,ga:pageValue&webproperty_id=&profile_id=95736296,6125383)
```

I’d like to add:
5.       Filters

There’s one problem with that.

If you don’t put any filters you get, for example, such 2 columns:

```
profileName,URL,metri_value
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/payment_paypal, 5
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal, 3
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/payment_error, 2
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/1232431234, 5
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal123, 10
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal77777, 12
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/1232asdf431234, 12
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/123243asdfa1234, 11
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/12324vxc31234, 10
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/123243asdf1234, 1
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/123243asdfd1234, 1
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/1232431asdf234, 1
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/1232431asdf234,1
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/12324dfas31234,1
```

Now, if I’d like to only get the lines containing ‘paypal’ I have to download everything which often is massive and then throw away 90% of that. In my example I need to get rid of all the ‘fluff’ URLs not containing PayPal.

This is because if I add a filter in my API query (e.g. ga:pagePath%3D@%/paypal*) I will get this:
Profile 1, PayPal, 27

This 27 will be the aggregate of all lines containing ‘paypal’.

The outcome I require is:

```
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/payment_paypal, 5
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal, 3
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal123, 10
Profile 1, www.whatever.uk/paypal77777, 12
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an extra % sign in your example expression. is it actually ga:pagePath%3D@/paypal*  ??

Suggest you use regex match instead of Contains -- the latter is case sensitive.

ga:pagePath%3D~/paypal

So long as you have include ga_pagePath in your query, you should get one line per matched row.